# Testing WebServices using tools

Tags: web-services

Anyother option to test webservices other than using SoapUI tool?

Answer (score 2):

Anything specific that you are looking for?

If not, the common tools that I have used in the past include :-

1. [WebServiceStudio](http://webservicestudio.codeplex.com/)
2. [Storm](http://storm.codeplex.com/)